# How to disable Xcode DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH expansion upon launch

Tags: xcode

When I run application from Xcode it expands some environment variables. For example it adds executable directory to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. And because I have libjpeg.dylib in executable directory my application fails to initialize with error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Reason: Incompatible library version: ImageIO requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libJPEG.dylib provides version 0.0.0
```

That obviously happens because of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH expansion. dyld tries to load my libjpeg.dylib instead of system one while loading system frameworks. For me such Xcode behavior looks illogical because you get different results when running application from Terminal and running it from Xcode. So I'm looking for any way of disabling such Xcode behavior.

P.S. Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in scheme's "Environment Variables" section doesn't help because I'll get DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set to MY_VALUE:EXECUTABLE_DIR.

Comment: Should you be putting the `.dyld` in the same directory as the executable?